# Rails rspec Error.should_receive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

When I want to test that a method raises an error its quite simple:

```
# There is a Widget model

# Method to test

class Example
  def perform(widget_id)
    the_widget = Widget.find(widget_id)
  end
end

# rspec test

describe "Example" do
  let(:example) {Example.new}

  it "does not find the record and raises an error" do
    expect { example.perform(0) }.to raise_error( ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound )
  end
```

But if that method handles errors:

```
class Example
  def perform(widget_id)
    the_widget = Widget.find(widget_id)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
    # (error logging goes here)
    return false
  end
end
```

Then the `expect __ to raise_error __` is not met, as the exception is handled. So what I'm asking, is if there is something which merely checks to see if an error was raised, irrespective of whether it was handled. Such as:

```
Error.should_receive(ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound)
```

There is always the option to work around the problem by checking to see if its logged, but this question isn't about solving this problem, its about the general solution of determining if an error has been raised

Comment: you should simply check it returns false

Comment: the whole point of specs is to check expected result, not implementation. nobody cares an exception was raised, only the result matters

Comment: Would you say that the `expect{__}.to raise_error` is superfluous and should be removed from rspec? Or that everything which can raise an error should be in its own individual method so that it can be tested in isolation with `expect{__}.to raise_error`, separate from the code which catches and handles exceptions? If there were a number of different errors which were all caught, and you wanted to write tests to check that given x get y error, given a get b error, how would you do this? Return the error as a string (instead of the boolean false) and compare?

Comment: I say that if your method may raise an uncaught error, spec it, if you raise and catch in the same method, dont spec that, its internal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RSpec allows you to set expectations for:

- The value of an object
- Whether an object receives messages at some point in the future and what arguments it receives them with
- Whether a test double has received messages at some point in the past and what arguments it received them with
- What behavior a block has on the outside world when it executes

With respect to some method you are testing, you can therefore test:

- What value it returns
- What methods it calls and what parameters it calls them with
- What errors it raises
- What changes in state occur as a result of it's execution

What you cannot do, however, is test what values are returned or errors raised by methods *that it calls*. That's consistent with the fact that RSpec enables you to test a method's externally detectable behavior, not it's internal behavior or the behavior of any code it may depend on.